# unordered_map insertion is creating bottleneck

Tags: string, performance, c++11, graph, unordered-map

So here I am trying to create a Graph data structure in which i have to keep track of edges according to their ids. So I am creating edge ids in string data structure as eid: sourceid_destinationid

```
using namespace std;

class Edge{

public:
    bool operator==(const Edge* &obj) const
    {
        return eid==obj->eid;
    }

    std::string eid;
    set<int> rrids;
    int sourceid;
    int destid;
    int strength;

public:
    Edge(std::string eid,int from,int to);
    std::string getId();
    void addRRid(int rrid);
    void removeRRid(int rrid);
    void setRRid(set<int> rrids);
    void setId(std::string eid);
};
```

This is another class which I am using for adding and removing the edges.
hpp-file

using namespace std;

```
class RRassociatedGraph{

public:
    unordered_map<int,vertex*> vertexMap;
    std::unordered_map<std::string,Edge*> EdgeMap;
    int noOfEdges;

public:
    RRassociatedGraph();
    unordered_set<vertex> getVertices();
    int getNumberOfVertices();
    void addVertex(vertex v);
    vertex* find(int id);
    Edge* findedge(std::string id);
    void addEdge(int from, int to, int label);
    void removeEdge(int from, int to,int rrSetID);
};
```

When I debugged the code I found out that in the function add edge here the place where I am doing EdgeMap.insert the execution doesn't go to next line. It remains in hashtable for loop of some bucket entry. I can't debug this code frequently because I have to wait for 3 hours to get this issue. The code is working perfectly with small graphs. But for larger graphs where edgeMap has to store 800k edges. It goes in this hashtable infinite loop. I don't get this hashtable code. But is there something wrong with my data structure of creating Edgemap?

```
#include "RRassociatedGraph.hpp"
RRassociatedGraph::RRassociatedGraph() {
    noOfEdges=0;
}

void RRassociatedGraph::addVertex(vertex v) {
    vertexMap.insert(pair<int,vertex*>(v.getId(), &v));
}

vertex* RRassociatedGraph::find(int id) {
    unordered_map<int,vertex*>::const_iterator got=vertexMap.find(id);
    if(got != vertexMap.end() )
        return got->second;
    return nullptr;
}

Edge* RRassociatedGraph::findedge(std::string id){
    unordered_map<std::string,Edge*>::const_iterator got=EdgeMap.find(id);
    if(got != EdgeMap.end() )
        return got->second;
    return nullptr;
}

void RRassociatedGraph::addEdge(int from, int to, int label) {

    vertex* fromVertex = find(from);
    if (fromVertex == nullptr) {
        fromVertex = new vertex(from);
        vertexMap.insert(pair<int,vertex*>(fromVertex->getId(), fromVertex));
    }

    vertex* toVertex = find(to);
    if (toVertex == nullptr) {
        toVertex = new vertex(to);
        vertexMap.insert(pair<int,vertex*>(toVertex->getId(), toVertex));
    }

    if(fromVertex==toVertex){
       // fromVertex->outDegree++;
        //cout<<fromVertex->getId()<<" "<<toVertex->getId()<<"\n";
        return;
    }
    std::string eid=std::to_string(from);
    eid+="_"+std::to_string(to);
    Edge* edge=findedge(eid);
    if(edge==nullptr){
        edge=new Edge(eid,from,to);
        edge->addRRid(label);
        fromVertex->addOutGoingEdges(edge);
        EdgeMap.insert(pair<std::string,Edge*>(edge->getId(), edge));
        noOfEdges++;
    }
    else{
        edge->addRRid(label);
        fromVertex->outDegree++;
    }

}


void RRassociatedGraph::removeEdge(int from, int to,int rrSetID) {
    vertex* fromVertex = find(from);
    std::string eid=std::to_string(from);
    eid+="_"+std::to_string(to);
    if(EdgeMap.count(eid)==1){
        Edge* e=EdgeMap.find(eid)->second;
        if(fromVertex->removeOutgoingEdge(e,rrSetID)){
            EdgeMap.erase(eid);
            delete e;
        }
    }
}
```

this is the place where it keeps going into this for loop. The insertion time of map should be very less but this is creating bottleneck in my code.

```
template <class _Tp, class _Hash, class _Equal, class _Alloc>
void
__hash_table<_Tp, _Hash, _Equal, _Alloc>::__rehash(size_type __nbc)
{
#if _LIBCPP_DEBUG_LEVEL >= 2
    __get_db()->__invalidate_all(this);
#endif  // _LIBCPP_DEBUG_LEVEL >= 2
    __pointer_allocator& __npa = __bucket_list_.get_deleter().__alloc();
    __bucket_list_.reset(__nbc > 0 ?
                      __pointer_alloc_traits::allocate(__npa, __nbc) : nullptr);
    __bucket_list_.get_deleter().size() = __nbc;
    if (__nbc > 0)
    {
        for (size_type __i = 0; __i < __nbc; ++__i)
            __bucket_list_[__i] = nullptr;
        __next_pointer __pp = __p1_.first().__ptr();
        __next_pointer __cp = __pp->__next_;
        if (__cp != nullptr)
        {
            size_type __chash = __constrain_hash(__cp->__hash(), __nbc);
            __bucket_list_[__chash] = __pp;
            size_type __phash = __chash;
            for (__pp = __cp, __cp = __cp->__next_; __cp != nullptr;
                                                           __cp = __pp->__next_)
            {
                __chash = __constrain_hash(__cp->__hash(), __nbc);
                if (__chash == __phash)
                    __pp = __cp;
                else
                {
                    if (__bucket_list_[__chash] == nullptr)
                    {
                        __bucket_list_[__chash] = __pp;
                        __pp = __cp;
                        __phash = __chash;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        __next_pointer __np = __cp;
                        for (; __np->__next_ != nullptr &&
                               key_eq()(__cp->__upcast()->__value_,
                                        __np->__next_->__upcast()->__value_);
                                                           __np = __np->__next_)
                            ;
                        __pp->__next_ = __np->__next_;
                        __np->__next_ = __bucket_list_[__chash]->__next_;
                        __bucket_list_[__chash]->__next_ = __cp;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have many files so I can't put the whole code. I am not that good in c++. Please let me know if I have to implement it some other way. I have to use hashMap because I also need faster search.

Comment: If hashing the string is the bottleneck then.. don't do that. Use a `std::pair<int, int>` for `eid` instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably experiencing re-hash at insert. Unordered_map has number of buckets. When they are filled worst case insert time is O(size()).
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert
Rehashing occurs only if the new number of elements is greater than max_load_factor()*bucket_count().

What you may do with your current setup is:
1. Growth map at the init of the program, as usually number of buckets doesn't shrink.
2. Change from std::unordered_map to Boost::intrusive_map, where you can manager number of buckets manually.